# How should I manage data sending?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm writing an app, which uses bluetooth. I've paired the device with my laptop, in the phone's preferences. My question is, Is it enough if I just write a method which send data to the my laptop, without pairing, connecting etc.?

How should I write this simple method? I've tried it based on the android api guide, but it doesn't work. :S

Comment: Show us what you have so we can try and show you where you have went wrong

Comment: I've created the sample class from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html here, Managing connections. And the phone does FC, if I hit a button and call the write method.

Comment: I wan tot implement only that class (manage Connection) to my app. And send a simple string to my laptop.